# icon background transparency loss for Huawei Ascend Y330

Tags: android

I have an app icon png created in photoshop with full background transparency. The icon appears as expected at the top left of actionbar on a number of devices I tested with. However testing on the  Huawei Ascend Y330 it appears that there's some loss in transparency (see image below) with there being some white now on the background. Anyone any ideas on this?

[image: icon has white where transparent is expected]

Comment: use android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: thanks but the actionbar is picking up icon from manifest. Is there another way to specify icon for actionbar and specify transparency? <application
        ....
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: Same issue with the Huawei Honor 4X, except the background is green instead of white. Affects a lot of apps. Probably a bug in EMUI.